# org.springframework.expression.spel.spelevaluationexception EL1008e property or field ‘queueManager ’can not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I am trying to create a MQConnectionFactory using @ Bean annotation which is invoked by SpringBootApplication. Below is the exception stack.

`Startup  failed ’org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionException’ expression parsing fail  nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.spelevaluationexception  EL1008e property or field ‘queueManagerName ’can not be found on the object of type org.springframework.beans.factory.config.beanexpressioncontext

**Config class is described below ***:-

```
@Configuration
class MQConfig{

@Value("${queue.manager}")
private String queueManagerName;

   @Bean
   public MQConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory(){

      MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();

      mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManagerName(queueManagerName);

      return mqConnectionFactory;

   }

}
```

**Usage is like below ***:-

```
@Component
QueueMsgReceiver{

     @JmsListener(destination="${main.job.queue}",concurrency="1")
     public void updateMsg(Message jsonMsg) throws     JmsException,ExecutionException,InterruptedException{

    }
}
```

**Invoker is like below***:-

```
@EnableJMS
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class})

    public class Application{

       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
       }

    }
```

Comment: You need to show your configuration, including the place where you have a SpEL expression referencing `queueManagerName`. The error implies you are trying to reference a bean that doesn't exist, but we can't tell without seeing the configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have updated the configuration. Please have a look

Comment: There must be more you are not showing; none of that will generate a SpEL evaluation exception.